# Overriding fill-paragraph in LaTeX mode

Tags: latex, init-file, auctex, fill-paragraph

I would like to change the behavior of `fill-paragraph` in certain modes (e.g. `LaTeX-mode` provided by `AucTeX`).

I could just rebind the key `M-q`, but I am also using `evil-mode` whose implementation of `evil-fill-and-move` uses `fill-region`. Ideally, my custom fill function to override both the functions `fill-paragraph` (so it works with `M-q`) and `fill-region` (so it works with `evil`).

Assuming that I have a standalone program `format` that takes in LaTeX code via `stdin` and output formatted code on `stdout`, how would I go about override the above two fill functions to use `format`?

(Note: this is similar to `vim`'s `formatprg` option.)

Comment: Does rebinding `M-q` affect `evil-fill-and-move` in anyway ? I do not use evil hence I am curious. If region is active `fill-paragraph` calls `fill-region` anyway. So you might advice or replace `fill-region` with your function.

Comment: I have no tried it, but I believe not. `evil-fill-and-move` is bound to the key sequence `gq` in evil's normal mode. Rebinding `M-q` should not affect this keybinding.

In some sense, my question is really two questions:
1) How to replace the two functions?
2) How to use an external program? 

The reason for 2) is that I already have an external, non-Elisp solution.

Comment: In that case you can solve part of your problem by `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () local-set-key (kbd "M-q") 'your-fill-function))` where `your-fill-function` is your custom elisp defun. This will set that key combo only in Auctex. You could probably use `shell-command-on-region` with the REPLACE argument to define `your-fill-function`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be better to have 2 functions, although one can be implemented in terms of the other. The reason being that a paragraph is an *implicit* region, so the input in both cases should be different

```
(defun my-format-region (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region beg end "format"))

(defun my-format-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (mark-paragraph)
    (my-format-region (point) (mark))))
```

In order to substitute functions to others, regardless of their keybinding, use remap keybindings:

```
 (define-key LaTeX-mode-map [remap fill-region] 'my-format-region)
 (define-key LaTeX-mode-map [remap fill-paragraph] 'my-format-paragraph)
```